# How can I use my JSON data to create markers on a google maps API?

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-markers, event-listener

I've got a bunch of coordinates stored in a JSON object to be used as information for some google maps markers. I'm trying to set up a "click" eventListener that will use the data from the JSON object and
create a marker in my google maps API but I'm at a loss as to how to tie it all together.

This is the code I'm working with.

```html
<select name = "Landmarks and Attractions" id = mySelect onchange="myFunction()">
                <option id="selected" value = "bigBenCoords">Big Ben</option>
                
var myCoordinates = {
            "bigBenCoords" : {"lat":51.5007, "lng":-0.1246}}
            
function myFunction(){
            var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
            console.log(myCoordinates[x]);
            return myCoordinates[x];
        };

function initMap() {

            const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                zoom: 12,
                center: {
                    lat: 51.509865,
                    lng:  -0.118092
                }
            });
            var markerValue = myFunction();
            console.log("marker value is", markerValue);
            new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myCoordinates["bigBenCoords"],
                map
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I'd advice to not use the `onchange` inline attribute. It's an ancient technology and isn't just as flexible as the [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method of an element.

```html
<select name="Landmarks and Attractions" id="location-select">
  <option value="bigBenCoords">Big Ben</option>
  <option value="statueOfLiberty">Statue Of Liberty</option>
</select>
```

First thing you'll want to do is select your `<select>` element and create an array for your markers. Before adding markers, you'll need to remove all previous ones. To do that we'll need to store the references to the markers.
Create an array called `markers` in which we can store the markers when creating them.

```js
const locationSelect = document.getElementById('location-select');
const markers = [];

const myCoordinates = { 
  "bigBenCoords" : {
    "lat": 51.5007, 
    "lng": -0.1246
  },
  "statueOfLiberty": {
    "lat": 40.684155,
    "lng": -74.0594181
  }
};
```

Now we'll need to create a function to remove *all* markers and a function to add a *single* marker.

The former function will loop over each marker and use the [`setMap`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#Marker.setMap) method of each marker to break the connection with the map. After looping it should clear the array of all markers.

The latter function should take a single `coordinates` object with a `{ lat: number, lng: number}` structure and the `map` to add the marker to.

```js
function removeMarkers() {
  markers.forEach(marker => {
    marker.setMap(null); // Disconnect each marker.
  });

  markers.length = 0; // This empties the array.
}

function createMarker(coordinates, map) {
  const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: coordinates,
    map
  });

  markers.push(marker); // Add the marker to the array to save the reference.
}
```

Now in your `initMap` function, create your map, and start listening to the `change` event on the `<select>` element. Whenever the value changes, get the current value from the select, choose your `coordinates` based on the selected `location` and then call `removeMarkers()` and `createMarkers(coordinates, map)` to first remove all markers and then add the new marker to the map.

```js
function initMap() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: {
      lat: 51.509865,
      lng:  -0.118092
    }
  });

  locationSelect.addEventListener('change', () => {
    const location = locationSelect.value;
    const coordinates = myCoordinates[location];

    removeMarkers(); // First remove all markers.
    createMarker(coordinates, map); // Then add the marker.
  });
}
```

Hope this helps you out. If you have any question, let me know below in the comments.

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked perfectly, I was beginning to tear my hair out trying to figure it out. All I have to do now is work out how to have a corresponding info window pop up when the individual markers are clicked

Comment: You're welcome. If I answered your question correctly then be sure to mark it as accepted. That way others with the same question will know this is the answer, and it's a way to say thanks. 

As for your next question, there are already multiple answers on SO about this particular issue (I myself have had to research it too), so be sure to look around.